# Utilizing SpawnProtocol.Command from Guardian Actor

Tags: java, akka, akka-typed

I need the `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command>` in another actor. I would like the GuardianActor to have a reference to `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command>` so I can pass this reference when I spawn the actor using the Guardian Actor, is there any way to do this? I don't see it is possible since we only get `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command>` after creating the actor system and guardian.

```java
ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command> system = ActorSystem.create(GuardianActor.create(), "System", config)
```

The only option I see is doing something like

```java
system.tell(new SpawnProtocol.Spawn<>(NewActor.create(system)), "NewActor", Props.empty(), system.ignoreRef());
```

in this case I will not be spawning `NewActor` using the guardian actor - which I think is not a clean implementation (correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you, you want to spawn actors with a reference to the `ActorSystem`.

Every actor can obtain a reference to its `ActorSystem` via its `ActorContext`; the `ActorContext` is typically injected by using `Behaviors.setup`.  You would obtain the `ActorSystem` by calling `getSystem()` on the `ActorContext`.  Note that it is an `ActorSystem<Void>`, but since the only way it really uses its type parameter is when you're using it as an `ActorRef`, the `unsafeUpcast()` method can be used.  Note that `unsafeUpcast` doesn't in any way validate that the cast is valid, but since there will typically not be confusion around the type (there being only one `ActorSystem` in a typical application) this normally isn't a problem; if an improper cast is made, it will result in the system crashing when a message is sent.

```java
// Apologies, my Java is pretty rusty
public class Actor1 extends AbstractBehavior<Actor1.Command> {
    public static Behavior<Command> create(int x) {
        return Behaviors.setup(context -> new Actor1(context, x));
    }

    private int x;
    private final ActorRef<SpawnProtocol.Command> systemGuardian;

    private Actor1(ActorContext<Command> context, int x) {
        super(context);

        this.x = x;
        // If doing an unsafeUpcast on the ActorSystem and there's a message
        // which will do nothing in its protocol, it might be a good idea to
        // send that message eagerly, so everything crashes quickly...
        systemGuardian = context.getSystem().unsafeUpcast<SpawnProtocol.Command>()
    }
}
```

When an `Actor1` wants to spawn an actor as a child of the guardian (to be honest, I'm not sure when you'd want to do this from inside of another actor: the purpose of the `SpawnProtocol` is for code outside of an actor), you just send a `SpawnProtocol.Spawn` to `systemGuardian`.

It's also worth noting that the `SpawnProtocol` can be handled by an actor which isn't the guardian: the guardian actor can spawn an actor handling the `SpawnProtocol` and provide a ref to that actor as a means to spawn an actor which won't be a child of the requestor.

Note that the `ActorRef` for the `ActorSystem` is the guardian actor and it is the guardian actor that will spawn the actor when you do `system.tell(new SpawnProtocol.Spawn...)`.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is mostly correct. I need the `SpawnProtocol.Command` system reference for use downstream. I want to spawn an actor in a manner that I am able to pass `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Spawn>` reference to that actor for use later. I have two questions, if `GuardianActor` extends `AbstractBehavior<SpawnProtocol.Command>` why does `getContext().getSystem()` return `ActorSystem<Void>` instead of `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command>` and is there a way to otherwise use `SpawnProtocol` without having a reference to `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol>`

Comment: Within the actor, it has no static idea what type of messages can be sent to the `ActorSystem` (viz. sent to the guardian).  Conceivably, there could have been a type parameter for the type of messages accepted by the guardian.

Comment: To use the `SpawnProtocol`, you only need an `ActorRef<SpawnProtocol.Command>`.  For an `ActorSystem<SpawnProtocol.Command>`, that's just taking advantage of `ActorSystem` extending `ActorRef`; since the primary use-case for the `SpawnProtocol` is when something outside the actor system wants to spawn an actor, that's why the docs and examples focus on having an `ActorSystem`.

Comment: For most cases, when spawning an actor from another actor's `Behavior` (so, for instance, even though the code running inside an Akka Streams stage or in an handler in Akka HTTP is running inside an actor, the code you're writing doesn't really know that fact), doing `getContext().spawn(...)`, which will create that actor as a child, is generally preferred (for one thing, you get an `ActorRef` right away instead of waiting for a reply).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sufficiently cleared my doubts!